# What is wrong with my selection sort function c++?

Tags: c++

```
void selectionSort (vector<string>& dictionary)
{
    string min;

    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < dictionary.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (dictionary.at(j) < dictionary.at(i))
            {
                min = dictionary.at(j);
            }
        }

        swap(dictionary.at(i), min);
    }

    return;
}
```

I entered 5 inputs: hey, ok, so, no, okay

Outputs: no, okay, so, no

Could someone explain where I went wrong with my sorting function? Thanks!

Comment: Ask yourself what happens if the inner loop **doesn't** find an element less than the one in the outer loop.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question is pretty clearly stated but your code snippet won't work as a stand alone program.  Someone who wants to run your code has to build a main that declares an appropriate `vector<string>`, calls `selectionSort` and then outputs the result.  None of that is hard to do of course but it does take time and effort.  Here in StackOverflow you'll generally improve your chances of getting a useful answer if your post includes what is known as a [mcve].  The MCVE lets your readers quickly (and easily) experiment with your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
void selectionSort(vector<string>& dictionary)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); ++i)
    {
        int m = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < dictionary.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (dictionary[j] < dictionary[m])
                m = j;
        }
        if (m != i)
            swap(dictionary[i], dictionary[m]);
    }
}
```

Basically when your `i-loop` starts you assume that `m`-th element is smallest and then inside `j-loop` you check remaining elements if there is a smaller element. If you find smaller element you update `m` (instead of copying actual strings). At the end of the loop you check if `m` is changed from `i`, and if so you swap elements at `i` and `m`.

[Here's full example with your input](https://ideone.com/eFJV7g), when asking question it's recommended to provide similar minimal example that can easily reproduce your problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;


void selectionSort(vector<string>& dictionary)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); ++i)
    {
        int m = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < dictionary.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (dictionary[j] < dictionary[m])
                m = j;
        }
        if (m != i)
            swap(dictionary[i], dictionary[m]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> data{ "hey", "ok", "so", "no", "okay" };
    vector<string> data2 = data;
    selectionSort(data);
    std::sort(data2.begin(), data2.end());
    assert(equal(data.begin(), data.end(), data2.begin())); // verify that your sort matches what std::sort does
    for (const auto s : data)
        cout << s << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

and the output is:

```
hey no ok okay so
```